# Copy/extract text on screen from any app?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm wanting to be able to copy text from an app that does not support traditional android copy/paste methods. I've tried OCR methods, but the font that is used cannot be read by the OCR.

Obviously the android system understands what characters are typed on the screen, but how can this data be copied or exported?

I understand that this may required a rooted device, which is fine, I'm just curious as to how I would go about doing this.

Android 4.4.2

Thanks!

Comment: I anticipate a non-root solution for this. Accessibility apps need to read screen text too, and they don't need root.

Comment: To to various rules, you cannot. The accessibility runs as SYSTEM, allowing it to do its job with no root.

Comment: But would the app need to be setup to be read by the accessibility? Because I tried several apps and the accessibility option cannot read the text aloud.

Comment: Nope, Probably to a limitation. The only copy method I can think of for in apps is a screenshot, and busybox  may give the espeak command, which says inputted text out loud.

Answer (score 0):

I've had much success with [Google Goggles](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google%20goggles&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&gws_rd=ssl#) Android app.

Screenshot the screen, then share it to Google Goggles. You will get the text back.